# How to drop images into a JInternalFrame?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, jlabel, jinternalframe

I have created a Swing application that can import images into a label, but what I want to do is to put the imported image into an internal frame that will be created after the image is dropped.

1. Drop an image into the Java app
2. Create a `JInternalFrame`
3. Make the image appear in the internal frame instead of the label in the `JFrame`

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {               
                JFrame f = new JFrame("Testing");
                JLabel l = new JLabel("Drop here");
                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                f.setSize(600, 600);
                f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                f.setVisible(true);
                f.add(l);
                l.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
                
           l.setTransferHandler(new TransferHandler() {         
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        public static final DataFlavor[] SUPPORTED_DATA_FLAVORS = new DataFlavor[]{
            DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor,
            DataFlavor.imageFlavor
        };
        @Override
        public boolean canImport(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
            System.out.println("1");
            for (DataFlavor flavor : SUPPORTED_DATA_FLAVORS) {
                if (!support.isDataFlavorSupported(flavor)) {
                  return  true;
                    
                }
            }
            return true;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean importData(TransferHandler.TransferSupport support) {
            System.out.println("2");
            new Test();
            JInternalFrame  mb = new JInternalFrame("Frame title4", true, true, true);
            JLabel la = new JLabel("here");
            mb.setSize(400, 300);
            l.add(mb);
            la.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
            mb.add(la);
            mb.setVisible(true);  
      
                if (canImport(support)) {
                    try {
                        Transferable t = support.getTransferable();
                        Component component = support.getComponent();
                        if (component instanceof JLabel) {
                            Image image = null;
                            if (support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.imageFlavor)) {
                                image = (Image) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.imageFlavor);
                            } else if (support.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                                @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
                                List files = (List) t.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                                if (files.size() > 0) {
                                    image = ImageIO.read((File) files.get(0));
                                }
                            }
                            ImageIcon icon = null;
                            if (image != null) {
                                icon = new ImageIcon(image);
                            }
                            ((JLabel) component).setIcon(icon);
                            return true;
                        }
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
}}
```

Comment: 1) Start with changing `((JLabel) component).setIcon(icon);` to `la.setIcon(icon);` 2) Note that a `JInternalFrame` needs to be added to a `JDesktopPane.

Comment: .. 3) `public class Test` The class would be better called `TestDropImageToInternalFrame`. Yes, it's more typing, but it has a variety of advantages, including descriptive clarity and lowering the chance of a name clash in the single package that people might use for testing SO code.

Comment: Ask yourself the question, "what's the difference between dropping a image on a label and dropping an image on an internal frame?" - this will help identify the areas of the code which need to change

Answer (score 1):

Drop and image on a frame, panel, label, internal frame, is all effectively the same thing.  For me, I'd focus on common denominator to make things easier, for me, this means a `JPanel`.

A `JPanel` can be added to a frame, internal frame another panel/container and can make decisions about how to present the drop, in this case, it can use a `JLabel` to present an image.

So, based on [how to drag and drop files from a directory in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597233/how-to-drag-and-drop-files-from-a-directory-in-java/13597635#13597635) and [Java Drag-n-Drop files of specific extension on JFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15080244/java-drag-n-drop-files-of-specific-extension-on-jframe/15080654#15080654)

You could do something like...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DnDConstants;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDragEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetEvent;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetListener;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TooManyListenersException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JInternalFrame littleFrame = new JInternalFrame("Hello", true, true, true, true);
                littleFrame.add(new DropPane());
                littleFrame.pack();
                littleFrame.setVisible(true);

                JDesktopPane desktopPane = new JDesktopPane();
                desktopPane.add(littleFrame);
                desktopPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400, 400));

                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(desktopPane);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class DropPane extends JPanel {

        private DropTarget dropTarget;
        private DropTargetHandler dropTargetHandler;
        private Point dragPoint;
        private boolean dragAccepted;

        private boolean dragOver = false;
        private JLabel message;

        public DropPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            message = new JLabel();
            add(message);

        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        protected DropTarget getMyDropTarget() {
            if (dropTarget == null) {
                dropTarget = new DropTarget(this, DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY_OR_MOVE, null);
            }
            return dropTarget;
        }

        protected DropTargetHandler getDropTargetHandler() {
            if (dropTargetHandler == null) {
                dropTargetHandler = new DropTargetHandler();
            }
            return dropTargetHandler;
        }

        @Override
        public void addNotify() {
            super.addNotify();
            try {
                getMyDropTarget().addDropTargetListener(getDropTargetHandler());
            } catch (TooManyListenersException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void removeNotify() {
            super.removeNotify();
            getMyDropTarget().removeDropTargetListener(getDropTargetHandler());
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            if (dragOver) {
                Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
                if (dragAccepted) {
                    g2d.setColor(new Color(0, 255, 0, 64));
                } else {
                    g2d.setColor(new Color(255, 0, 0, 64));
                }
                g2d.fill(new Rectangle(getWidth(), getHeight()));
                if (dragPoint != null) {
                    int x = dragPoint.x - 25;
                    int y = dragPoint.y - 25;
                    g2d.setColor(Color.BLACK);
                    g2d.drawRect(x, y, 50, 50);
                }
                g2d.dispose();
            }
        }

        protected void importedImage(final Image image) {
            Runnable run = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (image == null) {
                        message.setIcon(null);
                    } else {
                        message.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                    }
                }
            };
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(run);
        }

        protected void importFailed(final String message) {
            SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(DropPane.this, message, "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
                }
            });
        }

        protected class DropTargetHandler implements DropTargetListener {

            private String[] validExtenions = new String[]{
                ".png", ".jpeg", ".jpeg", "bmp", "gif"
            };

            protected boolean canAcceptFile(File file) {
                String name = file.getName().toLowerCase();
                for (String ext : validExtenions) {
                    if (name.endsWith(ext)) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }
                return false;
            }

            protected File acceptableFileFrom(Transferable transferable) throws UnsupportedFlavorException, IOException {
                Object transferData = transferable.getTransferData(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor);
                if (transferData == null) {
                    return null;
                }
                List fileList = (List) transferData;
                if (fileList.size() > 1) {
                    return null;
                }
                File file = (File) fileList.get(0);
                if (canAcceptFile(file)) {
                    return file;
                }
                return null;
            }

            protected boolean canAcceptDrag(Transferable transferable) {
                if (transferable == null) {
                    return true;
                }
                try {
                    File file = acceptableFileFrom(transferable);
                    if (file == null) {
                        return true;
                    }
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException ex) {
                    Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
                    return false;
                }
                return false;
            }

            protected boolean acceptsDrag(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
                if (dtde.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                    Transferable transferable = dtde.getTransferable();
                    if (DropTargetHandler.this.canAcceptDrag(transferable)) {
                        dtde.acceptDrag(DnDConstants.ACTION_COPY);
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        dtde.rejectDrag();
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    dtde.rejectDrag();
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void dragEnter(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
                boolean accepted = acceptsDrag(dtde);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DragUpdate(true, dtde.getLocation(), accepted));
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void dragOver(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
                boolean accepted = acceptsDrag(dtde);
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DragUpdate(true, dtde.getLocation(), accepted));
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void dropActionChanged(DropTargetDragEvent dtde) {
            }

            @Override
            public void dragExit(DropTargetEvent dte) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DragUpdate(false, null, false));
                repaint();
            }

            @Override
            public void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new DragUpdate(false, null, false));
                importedImage(null);
                if (dtde.isDataFlavorSupported(DataFlavor.javaFileListFlavor)) {
                    dtde.acceptDrop(dtde.getDropAction());

                    try {
                        Transferable transferable = dtde.getTransferable();
                        File file = acceptableFileFrom(transferable);
                        if (file == null) {
                            importFailed("Not a supported image file");
                            dtde.dropComplete(false);
                        } else {
                            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(file);
                            dtde.dropComplete(true);
                            importedImage(image);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                        dtde.dropComplete(false);
                        importFailed("Not a supported image format");
                    }
                } else {
                    dtde.rejectDrop();
                }
            }
        }

        public class DragUpdate implements Runnable {

            private boolean dragOver;
            private Point dragPoint;
            private boolean accepted;

            public DragUpdate(boolean dragOver, Point dragPoint, boolean accepted) {
                this.dragOver = dragOver;
                this.dragPoint = dragPoint;
                this.accepted = accepted;
            }

            @Override
            public void run() {
                DropPane.this.dragOver = dragOver;
                DropPane.this.dragPoint = dragPoint;
                DropPane.this.dragAccepted = accepted;
                DropPane.this.repaint();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

*nb:* On MacOS, you can't pre-process the `Transferable` data.  It did work on Windows way back when I was using Windows 7, I can't verify if it still works.

Comment: Nice one buddy, also glad to see you still active... long time. Funny I've started doing Swing using Kotlin, random I know, but this was the first post I saw since I tried it out. Somehow Swing still holds a dear place in my heart and using it with Kotlin feels like its got a little bit of new life injected in!